# How to add image next to other images?

Tags: html, css

So i adding an image in HTML, i want to add more images next to it. but every time i try, it always placed in the next line of the web. should i use CSS? and what tag or element that i need to use?

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html> 
  <img src="imageone"/>
  <img src="imagetwo"/>
  <!-- i want "imageone" to be placed next to "imagetwo"-->
</html>
```

Comment: You do realize that `imageone` might not be a desired image?

Comment: And your answer is: use `body {display: flex;}` - just... I'm not sure you want to *just* flex row your body ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest the images in a parent `div` and give it a class. Then use `flex`.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin: auto;
}

.wrapper img {
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300/000/fff" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300/000/fff" />
</div>
</html>
```